# Apollo Client, React, event when cache enabled

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

```
const sidebar = ({ selectedSidebarItem, selectItemCb }) => {
      const doExcelExport = () => {
        const data = client.readQuery({ query: getLeveransprojektOrders });
        const rows = data.projectOrders.map(order => Object.keys(order).map(key => order[key]));
        ....
      };

      return (
        <div className="sidebar">
          <button disabled={some condition}>Export excel</button> 
        </div>
      );
    };
```

I need to disable a button until there are items in the Apollo cache. Is there any built in way of doing this? Can't find anything about it in the docs.

Comment: And how do they appear in cache? Why do you need to disable a button if there are no items in cache? What if you just check if your data array is empty? Or if a query is still in progress. Or both: check if query status is `loading` or data array has no items.

Comment: Yes but how do I check if the query is loading?

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to Query's `loading` prop from render prop function like so:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Query } from "react-apollo";

const GET_DOGS = gql`
  {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;

const Dogs = ({ onDogSelected }) => (
  <Query query={GET_DOGS}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return "Loading...";
      if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

      return (
        <select name="dog" onChange={onDogSelected}>
          {data.dogs.map(dog => (
            <option key={dog.id} value={dog.breed}>
              {dog.breed}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      );
    }}
  </Query>
);
```

[Check docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#basic) for more details.

Or you can pass this prop to your component using HOC.

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'

const Dogs = ({ loading, dogs }) => <div>{loading && "Loading..."}</div>

const withDogs = graphql(GET_DOGS, {
  props: ({ data: { loading, error, dogs } }) => ({
    loading,
    error,
    dogs
  })
})

export default withDogs(Dogs)
```

Note that you probably don't need to load data directly in event handler like you do.